# Node js and new when using require

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I've been trying to sort out the include of other js files within node.js.

I've read all about the require function and other alternatives and decided to go with the require function (as the code will only ever be used on node.js, not in a browser).

In my code I'm using prototypes to create an 'object' which I later wish to create an instance off.

To get it to work I've been writing code like the following (lets call it vehicle.js):

```
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

module.exports = Vehicle;

util.inherits(Vehicle, EventEmitter);

function Vehicle(options) {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    options = options || {};
    ...
}

Vehicle.prototype._doStartEvent = function(data) {
    this.emit('start', data);
};

Vehicle.prototype.testRun = function() {
    this._doStartEvent();
};
```

Then in my main js (lets call it server.js), I have the following:

```
var test = exports;
exports.Vehicle = require('./vehicle.js');

var remoteVehicle = new test.Vehicle({address: "192.168.1.3"});

remoteVehicle.on('start', function(d) {console.log('started');});

remoteVehicle.testRun();
```

Now this all works fine, but I do not have a good understanding of what is going on.

My main concern is the use of `var test = exports;` and then `exports.Vehicle = require(...)`.

I tried just doing something like `var vehicle = require(...).Vehicle` and `var vehicle = require(...)`, with the goal of just using `new Vehicle` or similar, but I couldn't get it to work.

Am I forced to use exports and if so why?

Please note I've been using the AR Drone project as an example, the above code is based on how they have done their modules internally. Refer to [Client.js](https://github.com/felixge/node-ar-drone/blob/master/lib/Client.js) and [index.js](https://github.com/felixge/node-ar-drone/blob/master/index.js).

Comment: This Mastering Node eBook is good: http://visionmedia.github.com/masteringnode/book.html

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny How is this a duplicate? This question was asked first (this was asked 3rd Jan 2013, the one you claim it's a duplicate of was asked 11th July 2013). If you think they're duplicates then the other question is the duplicate, not this one.

Comment: @Metalskin sorry, I was confused by the title. I re-red your question more carefully, and I think I was mistaken about it being a duplicate.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny no worries, no harm no foul :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

result of `require` is a reference to exports object which is function in your case. Just assign to a variable with the same name as class (or any other) and use as a parameter to `new`

```
var Vehicle = require('./vehicle.js');

var remoteVehicle = new Vehicle({address: "192.168.1.3"});

remoteVehicle.on('start', function(d) {console.log('started');});

remoteVehicle.testRun();
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, that worked. Not sure now what I was doing that wasn't working, as I thought I tried what your suggesting. I suspect I was getting confused and doing `var Vehicle = require('./vehicle.js').Vehicle;` due to some googling I had been doing.