# Nodejs new require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

Are these two lines the same?

```
var myModule = new require('my-module')
```

and:

```
var myModule = require('my-module')
```

The former helps intelliJ Idea (or Webstorm) to do autocompletion on methods (e.g "model" in mongoose)  (at least it doesn't show the annoying yellow underline that says "Unresolved function or method"

Comment: Relevant, possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134004/node-js-and-new-when-using-require

Comment: Trufa I read that question, and I thought it was more specific than mine. I simply want to know if adding the keyword "new" in any scenario makes no difference, that's all.

Comment: @arg20 did you find another workaround to this IntelliJ/Webstorm issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of JavaScript, **they're not the same**. In terms of `require()` as a function? **It seems so**, but I'd still advise against doing it.

Using `new` does a lot [under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650892/what-does-the-new-keyword-do-under-the-hood). `require()` will be affected by the use of `new`, as it's internal value of `this` will change.

```
var foo = {
    path: '/foo/bar/',

    require: function (module) {
        console.log(this.path + module);
    }
};

foo.require('baz'); // logs /foo/bar/baz
new foo.require('trev'); // logs undefinedtrev
```

Currently `require()` seems not to use `this` at all (as it's behaviour doesn't change whether you change the value of this or not). However, this isn't guaranteed to be the case in the future; it isn't documented.

**TL;DR:** don't use it.

Answer (score 5):

#### Instantiating what is *returned by* `require`.

`new` should be used when you're instantiating a new instance of a class or function, and not otherwise.  You almost certainly don't want to instantiate an instance of `require`.

However, if you want to instantiate an instance of a class/function *returned by* `require`, you could probably do something like:

```
var myModuleInstance = new (require('my-module'));
```

The extra containing parentheses means you're instantiating the returned object, not directly instantiating `require`.